# How to import less files twice to enable theme switching

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I'm working on theming my application using less files. I have created variables less files and common less files.

```
@import 'commonlessfiles';

html.theme1{
 @import 'theme1variables';
 @import  'baselessfiles';
}

html.theme2{
 @import 'theme1variables';
@import  'baselessfiles';
}
```

Using the code like above.

My problem is its generating CSS files for the first part (theme1). Probably less won't allow duplicate import. As I'm importing `baselessfile` 2 times. (`@import 'baselessfiles'`).

output:

common css

```
html.theme1 .class{

}....
```

Is there any way I can tell the less to or force less to import file twice and use the variable file.

My output should be like below:

common css:

```
html.theme1 class{

}

html.theme2.class{


}
```

Comment: Never used sass but I do use LESS. Not sure what you are trying to do here but I don't see any need to import the same file 2 times. To change theme I imagine you just need to have a different class on the body

Comment: im Using less only. in my code above  adding class to html. I do have common less code with variables. so i need to import the less file 2 times to give the varibales diff values to enable the theme swicthing/

Comment: I think you should just define theme 1 and 2 less files and in them you just wrap everything in `html.theme-1` then you simply need to include the 2 files and it is done

Comment: If you import like that it will include the entire baselessfiles 2 times which I don't think you want

Answer (score -1):

Below code works for me using `multiple`

```
@import 'commonlessfiles';

html.theme1{
  @import 'theme1variables';
  @import  (multiple) 'baselessfiles';
}

html.theme2{
  @import 'theme1variables';
  @import  (multiple) 'baselessfiles';
}
```